# Duplicate process (strange issue)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to prevent opening help file more than once. 
This is the method I am using:

```
    public void openHelp()
    {
        int count = 0;
        string helpPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\MyApp\Help\eHelp.chm";

        System.Diagnostics.Process[] helpProcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process proc in helpProcs)
        {
            if (proc.MainWindowTitle == "Sample App Help")
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(helpPath);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

The idea is, if you find the process with the same MainWindowTitle, then do not start a new one.
However, this is not reliable. In some cases it still starts the process, even though one is already running. Is there an issue with a logic?

Thank you.

P.S. Of course the MainWindowTitle is "Sample App Help", at least that is what I see while debugging.

**Update: 
Issue only occurs when user has minimised help file. So I suspect something happens in the system and I need to check something. Any suggestions?**

Comment: Are you referring to a CHM help file?

Comment: Yep, exactly what I am doing. Of course, I cannot filter out by process name "hh" (appears for help file in processes) , because a user may be viewing different help file while I'm trying to open my file.

Comment: Try `if(proc.MainModule.FileName == helpPath)` instead.

Comment: I believe a `Mutex` can be used to signal between processes?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the minimized window with Spy++?

Comment: @PhilGan that works if you own the code, but I think Alex is seeing a problem with non-owned code (the CHM help viewer.)

Comment: @ZachJohnson Oh I see. I'm wondering if it's appropriate to stop the user from opening more than one help file at once; sometimes you want to have multiple windows open so you can check things as you work.

Comment: @gaynorvader interesting point, however causes an exception in my case, since help file viewer is 64-bit app, and my application is x86.

Comment: @PhilGan I thought about bringing the help file on foreground, just like Office and other MS applications tend to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Remarks section in [Process.MainWindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx)  contains the following note:

> The main window is the window that currently has the focus; note that
>   this might not be the primary window for the process. You must use the
>   Refresh method to refresh the Process object to get the current main
>   window handle if it has changed.

Could this perhaps be the cause of your problem?

What about keeping the process id of a newly started help viewer and before starting another one, just check if the old one is still alive.

```
int id = ...

try
{
    var proc = Process.GetProcessById(id);
}
catch
{
    // no process running with that id
}
```

Comment: It is most likely to be the cause. I will dig in this direction.